# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error (Its not duplicate)

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, iis-7.5

I'm running web application in Asp.net 4.5, Application was made in version 3.5.
It is showing these errors in every page when i brows in window.

**The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.**
**

> Detailed Error Information:

**
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       Unknown
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x800700b7
Config Error       Config section 'system.webServer/modules' already defined. Sections must only appear once per config file. See the help topic  for exceptions
Config File    \?\C:\Users\AbdulSamad\Desktop\Sky1Ex\Sky1Ex\web.config
Physical Path
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined
Request Tracing Directory      C:\Users\AbdulSamad\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\

> **Config Source:**

```
 129:     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  130:     <modules>  //error
  131:       <remove name="ScriptModule" />
```

Showing error in line 130

Comment: The Visual Studio 4.5 is available? God, I was waiting for so long!!

Comment: @P5Coder really funny, but not so constructive :)